# Modelling a voting poll in a graph database

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, graph-databases

I've modelled a voting poll for a RDBMS system. The structure is a bit more complicated than a conventional voting poll since users can choose to vote either for an option on the poll or pass on their vote to another user for a given poll.

My structure looks something like this:

```
Polls
id | title
----------
1  | Who should be president

Options
id | poll_id | title
--------------------
1  | 1       | Obama
2  | 1       | Bush

Vote
id | poll_id | user_id | vote_type | vote_id
--------------------------------------------
1  | 1       | 1       | option    | 1
2  | 1       | 2       | user      | 1
```

In this case, option 1 would receive 2 votes since user 2 gave his vote to user 1 who votes for option 1.

I realize that the data I am going to store is going to be fairly complicated to query in a RDBMS system if I want to visualise how the votes move between users. However, I don't have much experience with graph databases and would like some hints as to how I go around modelling this.

Answer (score 1):

It's always preferable, when making a DB model, to start with an information design model, and then transform this into a DB model.

In an information design model for your problem, options would be componenents of polls (so the UML class diagram would have a ***composition*** between `Option` and `Poll`), and votes would be relationships/links between users and options (so the UML class diagram would have a ***many-to-many association** between `Option` and `User`, the instances of which are the votes). In addition, there is a ***ternary association*** `User`-delegates-his-vote-in-`Poll`-to-`User`, the instances of which are the delegations.

From this, I get the following DB model:

```
Poll( id, question)
Option( poll_id, option_sequence_no, possible_vote)
Vote( user_id, poll_id, option_sequence_no, nmr_of_votes)
Delegation( user_id, poll_id, delegate_id)
```

Of course, we have to add a ***constraint*** that the number of votes by a use in a poll is the number of delegations plus 1.